# Migrating a File from Plugin to Theme and changing its path → instead create a REST endpoint

Tags: plugins, themes, paths

```
<?php echo plugins_url().'/jamesplugin/assets/library/classes/process_mailchimp.php';?>
```

The above is path of a file that is kept in a plugin, but I want to transfer that file to a theme say here →

```
inc/process_mailchimp.php
```

For this `plugins_url()` what will be its theme-equivalent?

Please let me know If I need to provide any extra information to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you trying to print out a PHP file's path, because it's not a good practice. But to get the equivalent function for themes, you can use:

- For parent themes : `get_template_directory_uri();`
- For Child themes: `get_stylesheet_uri();`

Both are without trailing slash.

### Important Note

Don't ping a PHP file directly from your plugin or theme's folder. Including a PHP file (for example, by using `require_once()`) is fine, but accessing it directly by the browser is not. The better practice is to even check if the file being accessed directly, and block the access:

```
if( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die();
}
```

`ABSPATH` is a constant, defined by WordPress, which contains the absolute path to your installation root. If it's not defined, it means that your file is being accessed directly, maybe by a hacker.

So, instead create a REST endpoint and use that. Here is a simple example for you.

First, create an endpoint to call. It's as simple as this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_endpoint' );
function my_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route( 
        'wpnovice/v1', '/my_path/', 
        array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'wpnovice_callback'
        )
    );
}
```

Then, do the calculation in your callback function and return the value there:

```
function wpnovice_callback( $request ){
    // Your code here
    return $data;
}
```

The final stage is to use the REST endpoint as URL in your Ajax call. Set your URL to this:

```
<?php echo rest_url('/wpnovice/v1/my_path/'); ?>
```

Comment: This is the approach to take, I cannot understate how dangerous it is security wise to have standalone files you ping from the frontend like that. REST endpoints are super easy to make, and significantly more secure