# Why the Path is different with the one coded in rest

Tags: rest-api

Reference URL from where the code is taken: [Writing WP REST API Endpoint in 2 minutes](https://tomjn.com/2017/01/23/writing-wp-rest-api-endpoint-2-minutes/)

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'tomjn/v1', '/test/', array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'tomjn_rest_test'
        ) );
} );

function tomjn_rest_test() {
        return "moomins";
}
```

Based on the above code the path should be this →

> https://tomjn.com/tomjn/v1/test

then why this:

> https://tomjn.com/wp-json/tomjn/v1/test

With what logic is this portion coming up →

> /wp-json/

This was the [Primary question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278140/migrating-a-file-from-plugin-to-theme-and-changing-its-path-%E2%86%92-instead-create-a-r) from where my learning started.

Comment: [@Mark Kaplun](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/23970/mark-kaplun) → Can you Please reply to this question.

Comment: My knowledge of this area is partial, and I will let tom to answer it since he seems on a crusade to promote this kind of technique ;), it is just not right to direct question at specific people on the main site. If you want to ask someone specific you can always pop at the "the loop" chat, where there is no "formal" code

Comment: it is just not right to direct question at specific people on the main site. → I will take care of this in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it shouldn't.

The first parameter is called namespace. It's like the scope for your functions such as this:

```
function my_function(){
    $data = 0;
}
```

You can only use `$data` inside that function. Same goes with the REST endpoints. The path `/test/` will be available only under its specific namespace.

You should choose a unique namespace for your plugin or theme, and build different paths for different endpoints.

The second argument is the path. It's like branches of a tree. Imagine a tree as a namespace, and its branches as paths. You can climb the tree, and then choose a branch to harvest the fruits.

However, both of these are under the scope of rest route, has a base of `/wp-json/` if you have pretty permalinks enabled, or `/?rest_route=` if you are using plain permalinks.

Check the code reference about [`register_rest_route()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) for more details.

Comment: Question #1 → so, in short, this method of rest API actually creates a URL that actually doesn't exist, Right? when I say that it doesn't exist then it means it is not some file such as test.php that is kept in some folder say /inc/ etc, but it is programmatically generated and then rendered at a function's call, which makes this safer instead of directly including a file as in this condition: [post where I asked a question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278140/migrating-a-file-from-plugin-to-theme-and-changing-its-path-%E2%86%92-instead-create-a-r)

Comment: Question #2 → In this; register_rest_route( 'tomjn/v1', '/test/', array(  /test/ could also be test.php or that is not possible or not allowed.

Comment: 1) Yes that's right. Every request or URL you enter will be redirected to `index.php`, none of the URLs actually exist. 2) I'm not sure if you can set an extension to the path, you can try it for yourself and see.